# Property does not show value

Tags: f#

I define a property in a class like:

```
type Customer() =
    let mutable _lastName = String.Empty
    member val LastName = _lastName with get
```

And in the method QueryData I assign a value to _lastName:

```
member self.QueryData () =

            // CODE
            let addressData = bp.GetStructure("PE_PERSONALDATA")
            _lastName <- addressData.GetString("LASTNAME")
            null
        | RfcCommunication ex ->
            let basedComm = ex :> Exception
            basedComm
        | RfcLogon ex ->
            let basedLogon = ex :> Exception
            basedLogon
        | RfcAbapRuntime ex ->
            let basedAbap = ex :> Exception
            basedAbap
```

In the main function I created an instance of Customer() and read the LastName property:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let customer = CustomerBapi.Customer()
    let ex = customer.QueryData()

    if ex <> null then printfn "%s" ex.Message
    printfn "%s" customer.LastName
```

The result is empty string. I tried to debug the program and see that _lastName is not empty

[image]

Why is the LastName property is empty?

Answer (score 5):

Your property should look like this:

```
member this.LastName with get () = _lastName
```

The type of property you are using is passing `_lastName` as the value to **initialise** it with.

---

Explanation from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx):

> Private values that hold the data for properties are called backing
>   stores. To have the compiler create the backing store automatically,
>   use the keywords member val, omit the self-identifier, **then provide an
>   expression to initialize the property**. If the property is to be
>   mutable, include with get, set. For example, the following class type
>   includes two automatically implemented properties.  Property1 is
>   read-only and is initialized to the argument provided to the primary
>   constructor, and Property2 is a settable property initialized to an
>   empty string:

```
type MyClass(property1 : int) =
    member val Property1 = property1
    member val Property2 = "" with get, set
```